# Drop few rows of a pandas dataframe using lambda

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda

I'm currently facing a problem with method chaining in manipulating data frames in pandas, here is the structure of my data:

```
import pandas as pd

lst1 = range(100)
lst2 = range(100)
lst3 = range(100)
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Frenquency': lst1,
     'lst2Tite': lst2,
     'lst3Tite': lst3
    })
```

the question is get entries(rows) if the frequency is less than 6, but it needs to be done in method chaining.

I know using a traditional way is easy, I could just do

`df[df["Frenquency"]<6]`

to get the answer.

However, the question is about how to do it with method chaining, I tried something like

`df.drop(lambda x:x.index if x["Frequency"] <6 else null)`

but it raised an error `"[<function <lambda> at 0x7faf529d3510>] not contained in axis"`

Could anyone share some light on this issue?

Comment: There is a typo in `Frequency` (you wrote `Frenquency` once) and it is `None` in python and not `null`.

Comment: What do you mean by _method chaining_? If you have multiple conditions, you can `&` them together, e.g. `df[(df.Frequency < 6) & (df.lst2Tite > 3)]`. That isn't enough in your case?

Comment: @scnerd by method chaining, I mean something like
``
 df = (df.rename(something")
            .drop("something")
            .assign("something")
        )

``

which is operating the dataframe by function and return a dataframe in each step, I think another words for Method Chaining would be "Pythonic"?

Comment: Thanks for correcting me,@mrCarnivore  The code I put here are just demos to show the idea, but it would make a lot more sense if I type it right :)

Comment: The term is a "fluent interface". Pandas *does* support this, although, I'm not sure it is necessarily pythonic or not - up to your taste I suppose. Note, most built-in python objects do not support a fluent interface.

Comment: Did you ever find a good solution here @jingezhang? Also looking for a chain-friendly way to conditionally drop columns.

_Edit: Actually realized the answer is simple in this case: use `.loc`, I'll update with an answer for future searchers._

Answer (score 3):

This is an old question but I will answer since there is no accepted answer for future reference.

`df[df.apply(lambda x: True if (x.Frenquency) <6 else False,axis=1)]`

**explanation:** This lambda function checks the frequency and if yes it assigns True otherwise False and that series of True and False used by df to index the true values only. Note the column name  Frenquency is a typo but I kept as it is since the question was like so.

Comment: I like this answer, however please refrain from explicitly return `True` and `False` when you can directly return the result of the evaluation of a boolean expression.
In your case, `df[df.apply(lambda x: x.Frenquency< 6,axis=1)]`, which  is leaner and cleaner =)

Answer (score 1):

Or maybe this:

```
df.drop(i for i in df.Frequency if i >= 6)
```

Or use inplace:

```
df.drop((i for i in df.Frequency if i >= 6), inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

For this sort of selection, you can maintain a fluent interface and use method-chaining by using the `query` method:

```
>>> df.query('Frenquency < 6')
   Frenquency  lst2Tite  lst3Tite
0           0         0         0
1           1         1         1
2           2         2         2
3           3         3         3
4           4         4         4
5           5         5         5
>>>
```

So something like:

```
df.rename(<something>).query('Frenquency <6').assign(<something>)
```

Or more concretely:

```
>>> (df.rename(columns={'Frenquency':'F'})
...    .query('F < 6')
...    .assign(FF=lambda x: x.F**2))
   F  lst2Tite  lst3Tite  FF
0  0         0         0   0
1  1         1         1   1
2  2         2         2   4
3  3         3         3   9
4  4         4         4  16
5  5         5         5  25
```

Answer (score 1):

Feel this post did not have the answers that addressed the spirit of the question. The most chain-friendly way is (probably) to use Panda's [`.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html).

```py
import pandas as pd

lst1 = range(100)
lst2 = range(100)
lst3 = range(100)
df = pd.DataFrame({"Frequency": lst1, "lst2Tite": lst2, "lst3Tite": lst3})

df.loc[lambda _df: 6 < _df["Frequency"]]
```

Simple!

Answer (score 0):

Would this satisfy your needs?

```
df.mask(df.Frequency >= 6).dropna()
```